# Opencart error: Modification Not permitted menu hide in admin

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

Modification Not permitted menu hide in admin is using the same ID code as the one you are trying to upload! in opencart 2.0.3

Comment: What's your question ?

Comment: want to edit menu of opencart

Comment: Edit your initial post please.